# UIAlertcontroller in custom TableViewCell WITH returned value

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, uialertcontroller

I've searched similar answers in how to displace an `UIAlertController` in a `TableViewCell` via `protocols` and `delegates`. I got that part working. But I got two actions in the `UIAlertController`. One of them confirms an action and returns true, and the other button is **cancel** and returns false.

I can successfully present the `UIAlertController`, but the program just runs through my code and ignore the logic in my **confirm** button. I think this is because the **delegate/protocol** method runs the `delegate` method in **parallel/asynchronously** and doesn't wait for the return value.

Here is my code in my custom TableViewCell:

```
var unattend: Bool!
let customAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Not going anymore?", message: "Event will disappear from this list, confirm?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let nevermindAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Nevermind", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    unattend = false
}
let unattendAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm unattending", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    unattend = true
}
customAlert.addAction(nevermindAction)
customAlert.addAction(unattendAction)

self.delegate.goingCancelled(customAlert, unattend: unattend))
```

Here is my protocol:

```
protocol GoingCancelledDelegate {
func goingCancelled(alert: UIAlertController) -> Bool
}
```

Here is my code in my TableViewController, and yes I did type in the GoingCancelledDelegate in the class definition just didn't copy and paste here:

```
func goingCancelled(alert: UIAlertController) -> Bool {
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { () -> Void in
    }
}
```

So the alert shows up, but my `UITableViewCell` code doesn't wait for the return value to process other logic. Any tips/advice/help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are calling `self.delegate.goingCancelled(customAlert, unattend: unattend))` without confirm action do this:

```
var unattend: Bool!
 let customAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Not going anymore?", message: "Event will disappear from this list, confirm?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
 let nevermindAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Nevermind", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    unattend = false
}
 let unattendAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm unattending", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    unattend = true
 self.delegate.goingCancelled(customAlert, unattend: unattend)) 
}
customAlert.addAction(nevermindAction)
customAlert.addAction(unattendAction)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get your answer. I see that you moved the self.delegate.goingCancelled() function into a UIAlertAction() statement in the action closure. But that code will be ran before the customAlert.addAction() functions, won't that be a problem? The actions not even added to my customAlert yet.

Comment: it will run only when you cill click `Confirm unattending` because that closure is called on its action.